# Trigger that flags on insert on one table and uses information from another table not working.

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm working on a database assignment. I'm trying to create a trigger that prevents a user from inserting a value into the charter table if the customers balance in the customer table exceeds 400. The trigger compiles with no errors but is not working. Any suggestions?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER Unpaid_Balance
BEFORE INSERT ON Charter
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE 
Unpaid DECIMAL;
BEGIN
SELECT Customer_Balance
INTO Unpaid
FROM Customer, Charter
WHERE CUSTOMER.CustomerID = CHARTER.CustomerID;
IF Unpaid > 400 THEN 
Raise_application_error(-20003, 'Customer has an unpaid balance of more than 
$400');
end if;
end;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably would like something similar to this (look at reference to inserted value - `:NEW.CustromerID` - that is what you forgot in your trigger):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER Unpaid_Balance
  BEFORE INSERT ON Charter
  FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE 
    V_Unpaid DECIMAL;
BEGIN
    SELECT Customer_Balance
        INTO V_Unpaid
    FROM Customer
    WHERE CUSTOMER.CustomerID = :NEW.CustomerID
    ;
    --
    IF V_Unpaid> 400 THEN 
        Raise_application_error(-20003, 'Customer has an unpaid balance of more than $400');
    end if;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
        NULL;
END;
/
```

But I'm strongly recommending you to do not put business logic in triggers. Do it in your application. It's very hard to control flow with triggers, because of them things are done automagically...